# elasticsearch partial searching with search as you type

Tags: elasticsearch

i have documents with a field called title having data like "the lord of the rings","lord of the rings","the ring",etc
I would like to do a search as you type feature.
So if user types "th", the order of the results should be -
"the lord of the ring",
"the ring",
"lord of the rings"
since i want the strings that start with "th" to appear first and alphabetically.
i tried looking into edgengrams, but that does it for every word in the string.
I would like to do it only from beginning of string.

Can you please let me know what are the analyzers i need to use to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the best link I've seen so far :
[Search like a Google with Elasticsearch. Autocomplete, Did you mean and search for items](http://www.bilyachat.com/2015/07/search-like-google-with-elasticsearch.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Match Phrase Prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) Query:

```
{
"query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
       "text": "the"
     }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps